# printf pwd for each string of a variable

Tags: shell, printf

I have assigned some files to a variable, and I am now trying to print this files and path to a txt file. 
However, it only prints the path for the first file and not the rest of the files included in the variable.

This is my code:

```
dbs=$(ls | grep -E "BNST|STN|NAc")

printf '%s\n' "$PWD/${dbs}" > ${sub}_DBSnuclei.txt
```

This is the result:

```
/Users/sbaldi/Desktop/WORK_DATA/OCD/ROIs_warped/Sub002/Sub002_BNST_50_L.nii.gz
Sub002_BNST_50_R.nii.gz

Sub002_NAc_80_L.nii.gz

Sub002_NAc_80_R.nii.gz

Sub002_STN_20_L.nii.gz

Sub002_STN_20_R.nii.gz
```

I would want the path to each of the files. How should I do it?

Comment: `ls | grep -E "BNST|STN|NAc"` it's `grep -E "BNST|STN|NAc" *`. Don't parse `ls` output.

Comment: @KamilCuk your suggested replacement command does something entirely different though. you'd really want to be using `find` for this kind of thing.

Comment: @KamilCuk You are correct [not to parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), however the line `ls | grep -E "BNST|STN|NAc"` should be converted to `dbs=( *{BNST,STN,NAc}* )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do any of the following:

```
for i in *{BNST,STN,NAc}*; do echo "${PWD}/$i"; done
for i in *{BNST,STN,NAc}*; do readlink -f $i; done
find ${PWD} \( -name '*BNST*' -o -name '*STN*' -o -name '*NAc' \)
echo $PWD/*{BNST,STN,NAc}* | tr ' ' '\n'
find $PWD/*{BNST,STN,NAc}*
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `xargs` just for that:

```
<<<"$dbs" xargs -n1 printf "%s%s\n" "$(pwd)"
```

For each line in `$dbs` variable it will run `printf "%s%s\n" <pwd output> <line>`.

Tested on [tutorialspoint](http://tpcg.io/JtEip1).

Answer (score 0):

With the simple filenames in your example output, you can use

```
printf "$PWD/%s\n" $dbs
```

The problem with your solution is that `printf` sees one argument. One argument with one `$PWD` at the start of the multi-line string.